# Get textBlock text that is inside a datatemplate from C# (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

i want to do some coding on textblock tap event for which, i required its text value 
my xaml is like below

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="auto" >
                    <TextBlock  Name="myTextBlock"  Text="{Binding Busnumber}"  Tap="buss_Tap"  />                     
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and then on textblock tap event i want to get tapped clicked text value

```
private void buss_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{        
    //i want to achieve this 
    // string aa= myTextBlock.text;
    //but this is not working so what to do here to achieve the same?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void buss_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock txt = (TextBlock)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(txt.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get **`TextBlock in sender parameter`**. Typecast it to Textblock and can get text from there:

```
string text = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;
```